# How aggregate functions work on one-to-many relationships in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an NSManagedObject Organisation and it has to-many relationship with NSManagedObject Employee.

```
//to-many relationship from Organisation to Employee
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *employees; 

//Employee has a property named age of type NSNumber
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *age;
```

Following line of code is giving max age within an Organisation:

```
NSNumber *maxAge = [organisation.employees valueForKeyPath:@"@max.age"];
```

I need to understand how `valueForKeyPath:@"@max.age"` is finding max age.

I am not sure that if `@max` is provided by NSSet or Core Data itself.

Comment: Did you mean to-many or a specific type of -to-many?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is down to a feature known as Key Value Coding.  Specifically @max is a "collection operator".  Other examples are @sum, @avg, @count.  KVC is supported by CoreData, but also by other collections such as `NSArray` and `NSSet`.  The Apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html) explain:

"Collection operators are specialized key paths that are passed as the parameter to the valueForKeyPath: method. The operator is specified by a string preceded by an at sign (@). The key path on the left side of the collection operator, if present, determines the array or set, relative to the receiver, that is used in the operation. The key path on the right side of the operator specifies the property of the collection that the operator uses."

Comment: This has nothing to do with SQL aggregate functions, right?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, KVC aggregates are done in memory rather than using SQL aggregate functions.  If you want the latter, take a look at `NSExpression` in conjunction with the `propertiesToFetch` and `propertiesToGroupBy` of `NSFetchRequest`.

Comment: Very well explained. I found this link to be helpful as well: http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/